Moment maps on Marsden–Weinstein–Meyer quotients
I'm learning a bit of symplectic geometry and more specifically about moment maps, so I'm currently playing around a bit with the concept. In particular, I'm curious about ways of constructing new moment maps.
(It's highly likely that my questions is very basic, so I apologize in advance).
For example, if we consider the action of $U(1)^n$ on $\mathbb{C}^{k \times n}$ via right multiplication, then this has moment map $\mu_1 \colon \mathbb{C}^{k \times n} \to \{ Z \in \text{Herm}(n) \mid Z \text{ is diagonal} \} \cong \mathbb{R}^n$ given by $\mu_1(X) = (-\frac{1}{2} \| x_1 \|^2, \dots, -\frac{1}{2} \| x_n \|^2) $, where $x_1, \dots, x_n \in \mathbb{R}^k$ are the columns of $X$.
At the same time, $U(n)$ acts on $\mathbb{C}^{k \times n}$ also via right multiplication, with moment map $\mu_2 \colon \mathbb{C}^{k \times n} \to \text{Herm}(n)$ with $\mu_2(X) = X^\ast X$.
I'm wondering if it's possible to have a moment map $\mu_3$ defined on some subset/quotient (?) of $ \mathbb{C}^{k \times N}$ where  $\| x_i \| = 1$  for all $i \in \{1, \dots, n\}$ and such that $\mu_3(X) = X^\ast X$, just as $\mu_2$. So in some way, I'm interested in $\mu_2$, but restricted to a level set of $\mu_1$ (in some suitable sense).
I read briefly about the Marsden–Weinstein–Meyer Theorem and it might be useful in this context. Under some technical conditions, the set $N := \mu_1^{-1}(-\frac{1}{2}, \dots, -\frac{1}{2}) / U(1)^n$ is a symplectic manifold, too. I haven't carefully checked these conditions yet, but I believe they might hold in my example.
If this would be the case, then would $X \to X^\ast X$ correspond to a moment map on $N$?
More generally, can one construct other moment maps like this? (that is, by sort of "inheriting" the moment map from the original space on the Marsden–Weinstein–Meyer quotient). Under what assumptions?
